# How to join duplicates and sum their numbers with awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have 2 columns in a text file with only one space between them. How can I join the duplicate 2 letters and sum their number together with awk

```
2 xx
4 dd
1 xx
8 mm 
5 dd
1 xx
```

So I can have this outcome:

```
4 xx
9 dd
8 mm
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '{S[$2]+=$1}; END {for (T in S) {print S[T],T}}' << -OEF-
2 xx
4 dd
1 xx
8 mm
5 dd
1 xx
-OEF-
```

gives

```
9 dd
4 xx
8 mm
```